# Updating a column after deleting a row

Tags: mysql

I'm learning to use MySQL and therefore I'm trying to make a simple inventory management. 
If I delete an invoice how can I not just delete from the invoice table and from the invoiceItemTable as well but update the "Amount" column with the subtraction value at the right store in my Inventory Table? Since if I want to do

```
SUM(inventory.amount) - SUM(SELECT amount FROM InvoiceItemTable WHERE invoice_id = 1 
    GROUP BY Product_id)
```

this will fail because subqueries have more than  1 rows. Below you can see my database structure.

```
InvoceTable
+---+----------------+----------+
|ID | invoice_number | Store_id |
+---+----------------+----------+
| 1 | 1234           | 1        |
+---+----------------+----------+

InvoiceItemTable
+---+----------------+------------+---------+
|ID | invoice_id     | Product_id | Amount  |
+---+----------------+------------+---------+
| 1 | 1              | 1          | 5       |
+---+----------------+------------+---------+
| 2 | 1              | 1          | 5       |
+---+----------------+------------+---------+
| 3 | 2              | 1          | 10      |
+---+----------------+------------+---------+

Inventory
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
|ID | Product_id     | Amount  | Store_id |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
| 1 | 1              | 15      | 1        |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
| 2 | 2              | 15      | 1        |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
| 3 | 2              | 15      | 2        |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
```

**UPDATE:**
Expectation after the queries:

```
InvoceTable
+---+----------------+----------+
|ID | invoice_number | Store_id |
+---+----------------+----------+
|   |                |          |
+---+----------------+----------+

InvoiceItemTable
+---+----------------+------------+---------+
|ID | invoice_id     | Product_id | Amount  |
+---+----------------+------------+---------+
| 3 | 2              | 1          | 10      |
+---+----------------+------------+---------+

Inventory
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
|ID | Product_id     | Amount  | Store_id |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
| 1 | 1              |  5      | 1        |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
| 2 | 2              |  5      | 1        |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
| 3 | 2              | 15      | 2        |
+---+----------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: The syntax for sum is: `SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'd need to use sum inside the subquery:

```
select SUM(inventory.amount) - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM InvoiceItemTable WHERE invoice_id = 1 GROUP BY Product_id) 
from inventory
```

check [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58860/2) for your database scheme and the running query.

this query should decrease the Inventory table's amount column according to invoiceitemtable table:

```
update Inventory set Amount = Amount - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM InvoiceItemTable WHERE invoice_id = 1 AND Product_id = Inventory.Product_id  GROUP BY Product_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help i updated my question with my expectation after the quires.

Answer (score -1):

```
SUM(inventory.amount) - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM InvoiceItemTable WHERE invoice_id = 1 GROUP BY Product_id)
```